# How can I improve a batch file with a conditional who copy a jpg file refferring to a specific extension and to a specific database?

Tags: batch-file

I created a .bat file with the following code in order to copy a random file from a directory A-POOL FOLDER into a directory B-FOLDER (with a fixed file name video.mp4). So, in the directory A there is a pool of .mp4 file, and in the directory B there is the the file video.mp4 (same name, but different video every time I execute my batch-file).

That's a code who do this. It perfectly works.

```
@echo off
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    cd C:\Users\aless\Desktop\example\A-POOL
    set n=0
    for %%f in (*.*) do (
       set /A n+=1
       set "file[!n!]=%%f"
    )
    for /L %%i in (1,1,%time:~-1%) do set "dummy=!random!"
    set /A "rand=(n*%random%)/32768+1"
    copy "!file[%rand%]!" C:\Users\aless\Desktop\example\B-FOLDER\video.mp4
    FOR %%G IN ("!file[%rand%]!") DO >"C:\Users\aless\Desktop\example\B-FOLDER\title.txt" ECHO %%~nG
```

Now the question (different from last time):
In the directory A-POOL I have a lot of .mp4 files. I changed manually **the .mp4 extension** of every file with a code who rappresent a food.

For example: Filename.pizza, Filename2.pizza, Filename.pasta, Filename200.pasta, Filename.cheeseburger etc...

I created another folder named "FOOD-DATABASE" (in `C:\Users\aless\Desktop\FOOD-DATABASE`) who contains a big database of images in `.jpg` extension of the foods. The file NAMES of the food database are equal to the file EXTENSIONS of the files contained in `A-POOL` folder

Content of FOOD DATABASE folder:
(pasta.jpg, pizza,jpg, cheeseburger.jpg... etc..).

So I need to add to the code a string/conditional who execute e command who say:

If the picked random File have the extension .pizza COPY pizza.jpg from C:\Users\aless\Desktop\FOOD-DATABASE into C:\Users\aless\Desktop\B-FOLDER\FOOD.JPG (fixed name file)

Actually I don't want to add this strings for every food type... in few word the code strings have to read the extension of the picked random file and copy from C:\Users\aless\Desktop\FOOD-DATABASE to C:\Users\aless\Desktop...B FOLDER\FOOD.JPG (fixed name file) the file with the same name to the extension of the random file.

It's a mess... I know ;) Thanks for your help!

Comment: You have provided us with perfectly working code, which doesn't exhibit a specific and reproducible issue. Along side it you've written text which appears to be unrelated to that code. What you need to do is revisit your question, using the [edit] facility, and provide the code related to your new problem, and with that, before and after file trees, so that your ramblings make sense on a programming level. Please make sure that you have taken the [tour], and read through all of the linked pages of [ask], before you make those changes, so that you better understand what is required of you.

Comment: I showed you in your last question how to separate the file name from the file extension.

Comment: Yes, i know and I implement the strings you gave me. A success. Unfortunately this random and conditional code at the same time are very complicated to me and I can't understand it with my ultra basic knowledge. I tried a lot but it's an advanced situation

Comment: Difficult to help you when the code you have provided does not exhibit the problem you are having and the description of your problem, especially some of the file paths you have mentioned do not match your code.  Open up a command prompt and type: `FOR /?` to read the help file. Focus on the very end of the help file that describes the `FOR` variable modifiers.

Comment: Ok i will take the tour and I will edit the question, thanks for your suggestions

Comment: To give you some hints, considering `%%i` as metavariable: `%%~xi` expands the e`x`tension of a metaviable `%%~ni` expands the `n`ame of the metavariable etc. see `set /?` and `for /?` from `cmd.exe` for full list.

Comment: Wow, it's very charming. I try to write FOR /? and SET /? and it appears a world of commands. It's very interesting but by the way I'm not able to decifrate and learn this language at a pro level in time. I think my only option is to hire a professional Are you interested to quote the writing of this code or can you suggest me a platform in which I can find a professional who can help me? In the maintime I continue to read the How to Ask page, maybe there is an apposite section on stack overflow

Comment: let me help you again.. `%%~xi` in a for loop in `somefile.pizza` would produce the extension in this case `.pizza` where `%%~ni` from `pizza.jpg` will result in `pizza` So typically `%%~xi` can be set as a variable, let's say `set "food=%%~xi"` then use variable expansion `echo %food:~1%` would remove the first character from that variable, making it pizza, so therefore `%food:~1%` would match the name of the `jpg` file name. So `%food:~1%` would equal `%%~ni` of the `jpg` file. We're professional enough to help you, but currently you need to provide some better detail in order to assist.

Comment: Meaning, you say you have `.mp4` files, but then you say you renamed some manually to `filename.pizza`. So did you change the extension? is it `filename.pizza.mp4` or did the extension change from `.mp4` to `.pizza`?

Comment: You are super professional... sorry, for professional i meant someone to hire. I haven't traslated it properly in eng.  Anyway I change the extension from .mp4 to .pizza

Comment: Anyway if you think that in order to reach my goal in a easily way it's better to rename the file in filename.pizza.mp4 for me it's ok. But you have first to know that at the end of the code I added this string suggested by Squashman FOR %%G IN ("!file[%rand%]!") DO >"C:\Users\aless\Desktop\DIRECTORY B\title.txt" ECHO %%~nG . This line makes possibile the writing of the file name into a .txt file. And I need only the file name without .pizza

Comment: but why? you renamed a valid file to a food name? Maybe it is a good time to clarify everything by editing your question and showing the reasoning.

Comment: Hope this can be more clear https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zm_7Jt117Po

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, we know that the extension of the one file is the name of another file. so these variable expansions are important:

```
%%~nG
%%~xG
```

The last `for` loop sets a variable `%food%` from expanded `%%~xG` which is the extension of the file and using a random example would be `.pizza` We just need to get rid of the `.` and you have `pizza`. We do this by `%food:~1`.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
pushd "%userprofile%\Desktop\example\A-POOL"
set n=0
for %%f in (*.*) do (
   set /A n+=1
   set "file[!n!]=%%f"
)
for /L %%i in (1,1,%time:~-1%) do set "dummy=!random!"
set /A "rand=(n*%random%)/32768+1"
copy "!file[%rand%]!" "..\B-FOLDER\video.mp4" /Y
for %%G IN ("!file[%rand%]!") DO (
    echo %%~nG > "..\B-FOLDER\title.txt"
    set "food=%%~xG"
)
copy "..\FOOD-DATABASE\%food:~1%.jpg" "..\B-FOLDER\food.jpg" /Y
popd
```

*Notes!*

1. I am using `pushd` instead of `cd` and using relative path, not full paths as we are working in the same folder structure.
2. I can make out that you are running this on your own profile, so I replaced `C:\users\<username>` with `%userprofile%` in the event someone else wants to run it from a similar folder, their `<username>` will be different.
3. `popd` at the bottom of the script simply changes back to the previous working directory you were in before the last `pushd`. it is not needed for this particular script, but adding it so you can learn about it compared to `pushd`
4. All of the items I modified has some good help topics, you can find help topics on `cmd` by simply running the command name with an appended `/?` for instance `for /?`, `set /?` etc.